# Angular 2+ UI-Router Unit test with relative uiSref

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular-ui-router

I've got an Angular component (9.1.3) that has a UI-Router relative route on it:

```
<button class="ls-btn light-blue-btn new-btn" uiSref=".new">
  <span class="fa fa-plus"></span>
  <span class="new-btn-text">New Tournament</span>
</button>

<ui-view></ui-view>
```

When I run the app, everything works as I expect it to, but when the unit test for the component runs, I get an error:

`No reference point given for path '.new'`

The code for the unit test is about as basic as it gets:

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TournamentsViewComponent } from './tournaments-view.component';
import { UIRouterModule } from '@uirouter/angular';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';

describe('TournamentsViewComponent', () => {
  let component: TournamentsViewComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TournamentsViewComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [ UIRouterModule.forRoot() ],
      declarations: [ TournamentsViewComponent ],
      providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TournamentsViewComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

I have tried adding some states to `UIRouterModule.forRoot()`, but that gives the same error - I've also tried using `/base` for the `APP_BASE_HREF`.

I've been over the [UI-Router docs](https://ui-router.github.io/ng2/docs/latest/classes/_directives_uisref_.uisref.html) on uiSref, where it mentions

> If a component template uses a relative uiSref, e.g., uiSref=".child", the reference is relative to that component's state.

Adding states didn't work, the variations of the base don't work; can someone help me find what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround.  Instead of having to keep relative routes straight, I put all of the fully qualified state names for the module into a map, so any component using the `StateService` can go exactly where it wants.

In a config file:

```
export const STATE_NAMES = {
  state1: some.place.in.app,
  state2: some.place.in.app.child1,
  state3: some.place.in.app.child2
}
```

Then a function in the component to handle the route change:

```
goToState () {
  this.stateService.go(STATE_NAMES.state2);
}
```

Not sure if this is the 'right' way to do it, but it keeps the code nice and clean, so it's what I'm going to go with.

Comment: that's a good workaround, not sure it's a solution :)